# How to set ui-select to readonly mode?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Is it possible and how to make my ui-select readonly?
Of course I've tried ng-readonly="isReadOnly" where I define in my controller $scope.isReadOnly=false;
And of course I want to calculate it "in runtime" according to data from server that can change the state.

Answer (score 9):

Use ng-disabled instead of ng-readonly.

```
<ui-select ng-disabled="isReadOnly" ...>
    ...
</ui-select>
```

Comment: This does not allow you to view the options

Answer (score 1):

If you need to view the options and disable text typing, you can use **search-enabled** option

`<ui-select search-enabled="false" ...>
  ... 
</ui-select>`

[**DEMO here**](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/demo-disable-search.html)